# How to create a new column keeping the non repeated character on the previous ones in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a dataframe like this:

```
col1     col2     col3
a        b        b
a        b        a
a        b        a
c        d        c
c        d        d
e        f        f
```

I want to create another new column (let's call it col4) containing the only value that hasn't been yet repeated in each row. Therefore, my desired output would look like this:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4
a        b        b        a
a        b        a        b
a        b        a        b
c        d        c        d
c        d        d        c
e        f        f        e
```

I'm trying to find a solution as simple as possible to get this output, but for now all my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is only a single element that is not duplicated, we can loop through the rows and get the first non-duplicated element after creating a logical condition with `duplicated`

```
df1$col4 <-  apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[!(duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, 
            fromLast = TRUE))][1])
df1$col4
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "d" "c" "e"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "e"), col2 = c("b", 
"b", "b", "d", "d", "f"), col3 = c("b", "a", "a", "c", "d", "f"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```